# Stop $timeout when starting new controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I'm polling for my data every 2 seconds to keep them updated on the page. My problem is when I visit another page the timeout stays active. How can i cancel my timeout when I visit an new page?

```
function IndexCtrl($scope, $timeout, RestData) {
    $scope.rd = {};

    (function getRestDataFromServer() {
        RestData.query(function(data){
            $scope.rd = data;
            $timeout(getRestDataFromServer, 2000);
        });
    })();
}
```

//EDIT
I found a solution, but I'm not sure if it's a good one. When i save my timeout to the $rootScope, I can cancel it in all the other controllers.

```
function IndexCtrl($scope, $rootScope, $timeout, RestData) {
    $scope.rd = {};

    (function getRestDataFromServer() {
        RestData.query(function(data){
            $scope.rd = data;
            $rootScope.prom = $timeout(getRestDataFromServer, 2000);
        });
    })();
}

function newPageCtrl($scope, $rootScope, $timeout) {
    $timeout.cancel($rootScope.prom); 
}
```

Comment: did you tried `$timeout.cancel()`?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

There are couple of Angular events that are being broadcasted when route is being changed. You can listen for them within the `IndexCtrl` using `$scope.$on` and act accordingly:

**$destroy event**

```js
var promise = $timeout(getRestDataFromServer, 2000);
...

$scope.$on('$destroy', function(){
    $timeout.cancel(promise);
});
```

**$locationChangeStart**

```js
var promise = $timeout(getRestDataFromServer, 2000);
...

$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(){
    $timeout.cancel(promise);
});
```

`$timeout()` returns a promise object. This object can be supplied to `$timeout.cancel()` function to cancel the timeout.

Comment: Actually, it's $timeout.cancel(promise).

Answer (score 15):

Stewie's answer is perfect.  I just wanted to share this simple helper function that I use instead of using `$timeout` directly, so that I never have to think about this issue again:

```
function setTimeout(scope, fn, delay) {
    var promise = $timeout(fn, delay);
    var deregister = scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
        $timeout.cancel(promise);
    });
    promise.then(deregister, deregister);
}
```

I added this function to a service called `miscUtils`, and I inject that service instead of injecting `$timeout`.  Then, for example, to make an "update" function that runs every 30 seconds until `$scope` is destroyed:

```
update();
function update() {
    // do the actual updating here
    miscUtils.setTimeout($scope, update, 30000);
}
```

---

**Edit** for those confused about what's going on with `deregister`:

This function registers a listener for the `$destroy` event, but once the timeout has completed it is no longer necessary; there is no longer a timeout to cancel. [`scope.$on`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$on) returns a function that, when called, deregisters that listener. So, `promise.then(deregister)` cleans up that no-longer-needed listener as soon as the timeout completes.

Comment: This sounds like a very good solution. Could you share all the code, like a working example, inkluding the service definition, so for me as a beginner it is easier to integrate it in my own application? Thank you!

Comment: The `deregister` variable confused me for a while, I thought was the function to cancel the timeout but it's not. It's the function to cancel the cancelling of the timeout.

Comment: @dshepherd please explain because I'm still confused.

Comment: If the variable was named `deregisterDestroyListener` that might help?