# Need to stop ongoing operation when controller becomes background (or invalid)

Tags: angularjs, controller, routes, angularjs-routing, angularjs-controller

I'm writing my first AngularJS application. The landing page has two links `#/view1` and `#/view2`. Every link will call individual controller to render `<div ng-view></div>` individually.

The `view1Ctrl` will fetch data from server periodically. I can see ajax call in console every X seconds. Now I click `#/view2`, the app should use `view2Ctrl`. I expect `view1Ctrl` should no longer fetch data from the server. But actually it does.

```
.controller('View1Ctrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.update = function() {
    $http.get('/api/foo')
      .success(function(data) { /* got new data */ })
      .error(function(data) { /* error occurred */ })
      .finally(function() {
        setTimeout($scope.update, 1000);
      });
  }
  $scope.update();
});
```

I've two questions:

1. Is a controller always active after it is initialized.
2. What is the best practice to stop any background controllers? My idea is to check the `$location.path()`.

---

**Update 1:**

The controller is actually destroyed. But the operation `update` will invoke it by itself, so the operation will be called endless.

My current workaround will check whether the current location has been change. So it works. I'm looking for a more elegant way, if it exists.

```
.controller('View1Ctrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.update = function(path) {
    $http.get('/api/foo')
      .success(function(data) { /* got new data */ })
      .error(function(data) { /* error occurred */ })
      .finally(function() {
        if (path === $location.path()) {
          setTimeout($scope.update, 1000, path);
        }
      });
  }
  $scope.update($location.path());
});
```

---

**Update 2:**

A better way is to watch destruction and cancel an ongoing timeout promise. Thanks @pankajparkar

```
.controller('View1Ctrl', function($scope, $http, $timeout) {
  var timeoutPromise;
  $scope.$on("$destroy", function(){
    $timeout.cancel(timeoutPromise);
  });
  $scope.update = function() {
    $http.get('/api/foo')
      .success(function(data) { /* got new data */ })
      .error(function(data) { /* error occurred */ })
      .finally(function() {
         timeoutPromise = $timeout($scope.update, 1000);
      });
  }
  $scope.update();
});
```

Comment: [Good read here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16094940/what-is-the-lifecycle-of-an-angularjs-controller)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28657287/passing-values-in-angular-js/28657470#28657470 Have a look at it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are mentioned ng-controller on the body tag or the parent of your `ng-view`, In your case you should load the controller from your `$routeProvider` that will handle it,

**Config**

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/view1', {
      templateUrl: 'view1.html',
      controller: 'view1Ctrl' //load specific controller from here
    })
    .when('/view2', {
      templateUrl: 'view2.html',
      controller: 'view2Ctrl' //load specific controller from here
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/view1'
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
  <div class="wizard">
    <ng-view></ng-view>
  </div>
```

**Below are the answer of your questions.**

1. Now when `$routeProvider` load `view1.html` the `view1Ctrl` will exists, as soon as user navigates to `view2.html` the `view1Ctrl` will stop its working `view2Ctrl` will comes into a picture as you mentioned that inside your route configuration.
2. You should always use `$routeProvider` or `$stateProvider`([**angular-ui-router**](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/)) to set up routing inside you application, and load `templates` and `controller` on basis of routing. No need to check `$location.path()`

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Thpmrlnbit0cKTs8xFSk?p=preview)

**Update**

Your problem was with the repetitive function call, which was running in background even after controller scope has vanished from DOM.
The best way to clear out this function while redirecting to other controller.
I'd suggest you to put your `$timeout` promise(you used `setTimeout` changed it to `$timeout`) in one java script variable, and cancel that while leaving(unregistered the controller). While leaving controller `$destroy` event gets dispatched by angular, which is act like `destruct-or` of controller, you can use of it, you could cancel your `$timeout` promise inside that.

**CODE**

```
var timeoutPromise = setTimeout($scope.update, 1000);
$scope.$on("$destroy", function(){
    $timeout.cancel(timeoutPromise);
});
```

[**Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/3eIglLdGVbVv6xZ2c5Ik?p=preview) with canceling promise of `$timeout`.
[**Reference Link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17131807/stop-timeout-when-starting-new-controller)

Hope this could help you, Thanks.

Comment: It seems not to work. I've attached a runnable code example. I wish if you can confirm.

Comment: I understand my problem. The method `update` is a closure. It will call itself endless. I've up-voted your answer, but I still need a solution to fix my problem.

Comment: @stanleyxu2005 now what are you looking for, where are you stuck now?

Comment: I am using a recursive call (a closure) to fetch data from server. When I change page, the closure will not stop. I'm looking for an elegant way to stop it.

Comment: @stanleyxu2005 look at my plunkr and answer too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71520/discussion-between-pankajparkar-and-stanleyxu2005).